# How to remake the script so that the data is in div blocks?

Tags: javascript

Hello there is a script.

```
 var tableEl;
        
    function generate()
    {
    var GenSix = document.getElementById("GenSix"),
    numbers = (new Array(20)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i),
    result = [],
    qnt = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);
    
    GenSix.innerHTML = '';
    tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
    GenSix.appendChild(tableEl).className = 'GenSix';
    
    while(result.length < qnt)
    {
    var left = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 4).join('-'),
    right = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 4).join('-');
    
    //чтобы не были равны между собой
    if(left == right)
    continue;
    
    result.push([left, right]);
    fillTableWithContent(left, right);
    }
    }
    
    function shuffle(arr)
    {
    return arr.map(el => {
    return {
    item: el,
    sort: Math.random()
    }
    }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
    }
    
    function fillTableWithContent(left, right, className)
    {
    var tr = tableEl.insertRow(tableEl.rows.length);
    tr.insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode(left));
    tr.insertCell(1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(right));
    tr.className = className || "intsixone";
    }
```

This code generates a table like this

```
<table><tbody><tr><td>numbers</td><td>numbers</td></tr><tr><td>numbers</td><td>numbers</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

but it should be

```
<div class="wrap"><div class="one">numbers</div><div class="one">numbers</div><div class="one">numbers</div></div>
```

It creates tables with data, how to pass it so that the data is not displayed in tables, but in div blocks? Thanks

Comment: Create a [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that uses divs from your example html and insert the data into it. This will require rewriting most of your code because it uses a table object.

Comment: it's simple, you have to start all over again

Comment: what are you hoping for? free code here? ! what would be the general interest to which this site is dedicated?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one very simple way of generating the collection of `<div>`s:

```
document.getElementById("GenSix").innerHTML='<div class="wrap">'
  +generate()
   .map(([l,r])=>`<div class="one">${l}</div><div class="two">${r}</div>`)
   .join("")
  +'</div>'
```

I assume that you want to generate the divs in pairs. For that reason I changed every second div to `class="two"`. I also separated the code into a "number generation" and a "show in DOM" part, so it will be easier to maintain.

I also took the liberty of rewriting your `generate(n)` function in a slightly shorter form, avoiding repetitions: `gen(n,m=2)`. In the following snippet I took the parametrisation a step further and wrote the code in a way, that you can now generate a table with any given number of rows and columns:

```js
// === SHOW in DOM part ==================================
document.querySelector("button").onclick=_=>
 document.getElementById("GenSix").innerHTML='<div class="wrap">'
  +gen(...["quantity","cols"].map(id=>+document.getElementById(id).value))
   .map(r=>r.map((c,i)=>`<div class="cls${i}">${c}</div>`).join("")).join("")
  +'</div>';

// === NUMBER GENERATION part ==================================
function gen(n,m=2){  // shortened version of generate()
 const arr=n=>[...Array(n+1).keys()].slice(1), nums=arr(20),lr=arr(m);
 return arr(n).map(r=>lr.map(_=>shuffle(nums).slice(0,4).join("-")));
}

function shuffle(arr) {
  return arr.map(itm=>({itm,srt:Math.random()}))
            .sort((a, b) => a.srt - b.srt)
            .map(el => el.itm);
}
```

```css
input {width:30px}
.wrap {background-color:#def}
[class^=cls] {
  background-color:#eee;
  display:inline-block; width:100px;
  border:1px solid grey;padding:6px;margin:4px}
.cls0 {background-color:white}
.cls1 {background-color:#ffe}
.cls2 {background-color:#fef}
.cls3 {background-color:#eff}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="quantity" value="6"> rows, 
<input type="number" id="cols" value="2"> columns
<button>go</button><br><br>
<div id="GenSix"></div>
```

Here is the slightly modified version of your original `generate()` function:

```
function generate(qnt) {  // modified from OP
  var numbers = new Array(20).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i),
    result = [], left, right;

  while (result.length < qnt) {
    var left = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 4).join('-'),
      right = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 4).join('-');

    result.push([left, right]);
  }
  return result
}
```